# error in Flutter : Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: json, flutter, api

i have this error when i call the data from api the problem based in `DateTime` attribut,

error :  Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

```
required this.dateTime,

DateTime dateTime;

DateTime.parse(json["dateTime"]),

"dateTime": dateTime.toIso8601String(),
```

Comment: It seems that 'json["dateTime"]' is null. Try to check json value whether there is 'dateTime' key exist.

Answer (score 1):

Use This

```
"dateTime": dateTime.toString()
```

Answer (score 1):

Its Null safety issue when you are accessing: `json["dateTime"]` this value and parsing into DateTime like:-`DateTime.parse(json["dateTime"]` and if this value `json["dateTime"]` will be null then this issue will be occure. by changing little bit in your code you'll re-solve this issue.

```
required this.dateTime,

DateTime dateTime;

DateTime.parse(json["dateTime"].toString()),// this line you need to edit. 

"dateTime": dateTime.toIso8601String(),
```

Now if `json["dateTime"]` this value will be null then no any issue will be occure because null value will be convert into string. by adding .toString().